# Can't link app to Facebook page

Tags: facebook

I saw a few posts on Stackoverflow on how to link your apps to Facebook pages that have already been created. However, I can't do the same. The page that I want to use shows up as "gray".

[image]

Furthermore, the "Fablelane Community" page is what was created when I clicked the "create new page" button instead. It's not what I want (I want the existing page "Fablelane"), but apparently I can't pick it.

- I've tried renaming the page to the same as the application's name.
- I've tried setting the category of the page to Brand / App Page.
- Despite being visible in the list, I can't click it, and it doesn't give me a reason.

Can anyone help?

**Note: This is not related to any of the other questions found on here, since they all succeeded by doing exactly what I've already tried.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just deleting my page (goodbye to all my "likes").

After recreating it, it links just fine.

I concluded that it was a Facebook bug. I originally had an app several years ago that used to be linked. However, that app was deleted, but the link was not.

Now, after some recent changes, this caused me to be unable to link the new app with the page.

Comment: Ya this was the reason I have said that the page is linked with some app.

Answer (score 2):

If you are seeing gray color non clickable page name in the drop down list then ensure that your page is not already listed as the App Page for another application

Comment: Hmmm interesting. I am the only admin though, but I might have (at one point) had other apps that pointed to the page. How can I make sure that no app links to the page?

Comment: I think there is no official procedure for it. If you are only admin then you can cross check with your apps. Do you have other applications with the same name.

Comment: I most likely used to, but not anymore. There are only 2 apps, and none of them use this page. Could it be a Facebook bug?

Comment: no i don't think so because I also tried but everything is fine.

Comment: I tried everything. No luck. I am 100% certain that I am the only administrator of the page, and the app itself. The page is still grayed out.

Comment: trying to change the name of the page and the app but keep the name same.

Comment: Here's my new settings on the app (http://i.imgur.com/wFUIkm7.png) and when trying to set the page (http://i.imgur.com/0W96z54.png). No luck.

Comment: I have researched a lot and reached to the conclusion that it is only possible when and only page is using as app page in another application. Can you try to make a new application and try it again.

Comment: Yeah if you're the admin of both the app and page, the names match and the page is in the App Page category, the most likely reason you can't link them is that the page is already linked with a different app

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this merhod as described on the FB Docs:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/appsonfacebook/pagetabs/#url-redirect

Worked always for me at least.

Comment: Unfortunately, this isn't what I'm looking for. I'm looking for a way to change the page that's bound to the app, not just a page tab.

Comment: Sorry, then I misunderstood.